# Sliding Block Puzzle, how to approach this

Tags: java, algorithm, search, data-structures

I am taking an AI course, and the very first problem we are assigned is to create a program to solve the sliding brick puzzle.

Now, our professor hasn't given us any information on how to approach this. I am two classes in and all we covered is the definition of AI, and Agents.

I am completely lost with how to approach this problem. We are given text files that represent a board, and my code is already set up to translate the board as a 2d array, print it out, etc. (the easy stuff). But now I need to work towards actually solving it which I am clueless about.

Here is an example of a board:

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,3,2,2,4,1,
1,5,2,2,6,1,
1,7,7,8,8,1,
1,9,9,10,10,1,
1,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,1,
1,1,-1,-1,1,1,
```

`1` represents a wall

`0` represents blank space

`-1` represents winning area

`2` represents the "special block"

Anything `greater than 2` is a "non special" block

Does anyone know what algorithms I could use to approach this problem with? Or possibly a good resource.

Here is an example of the game itself:
http://www.mathplayground.com/slidingblock.html

Comment: Your professor would be a good reference. Have you scheduled a meeting with them? As it stands, your question is too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Trobbins The only thing that's holding me back is that he comes off as harsh/pretentious, and I am afraid of being scolded as to why I don't know how to approach this problem.

Comment: What puzzle is this actually? It's not an N-puzzle

Comment: @harold I included a link to an example of the game

Comment: you might want to check [path finding algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding#Sample_algorithm). you can represent your state as a node in a graph and the states obtained from the possible moves as children

Comment: @svs So I would be building the graph as I generate moves?

Comment: @Brejuro you don't need to build the graph you could just think conceptually is there but you should definitely store statistics like: visited nodes, depth, depending on the algorithm. let me give you more explicit instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you represent your states as

```
class State {
    int[][] a;
}
```

then you should implement the following functions

- `List<State> getNeighbors(State s)` - this function should give you all possible states obtained from `s` by making a valid move. What you should do is find all pieces and try to translate them up, down, left, right.
- `void solve(State s)` - this function should solve the puzzle by using some standard algorithm DFS, BFS, A* etc. You may also want to keep track of which states you've visited in a list `List<State> visited` or more effectively in a hash set `HashSet<State> visisted`, but for the hash set you'd have to implement the hash function.

Note that you could represent the states at `String` which would eliminate the necessity to implement the hash function.

If you don't want to search for the bricks in the every state you could represent the bricks as

```
class Brick {
    List<Point> points;
}

class Point {
    int x, y;
}
```

and, alternatively, represent the state as:

```
class State {
    int[][] a;
    List<Brick> bricks;
}
```

In this way, the finding of all possible moves would be easier:

```
List<State> getNeighbors(State s) {
    List<State> neighbors = new ArrayList<State>();
    for (Brick b : s.bricks) {
         // if you can move the brick up
         // create new state new_state_up as you update 'a'
         // and 'bricks' and simply add it to neighbors.
         // do the same for the rest of the directions
    }
    return neighbors;
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful, I'll see if I can get on the right track using these guidelines. One thing though, which is what I asked in a comment above. I'm confused on how to deal with two-long bricks.

Comment: @Brejuro I hope this helps

Comment: Yes it does, thanks a lot. I'll get working now

Answer (score 0):

The next part, would be a test which could tell you if you have solved it..

bool IsSolved( ... )

Then, maybe you could think what the legal moves are at any point?

Moves moveSet = GetValidMoves( ... )

That may throw up how to approach this?

Comment: The thing I'm confused about is how I could find possible moves? I know there are searching algorithms, but is there one that I should be focusing on?

Comment: @Brejuro you already know the moves (blocks can move up/right/down/left if the space they would occupy is free), the search is to chain moves such that the goal is reached

Comment: @harold I'm not sure how I would treat blocks that are two spaces long

Comment: @Brejuro as a block that is two spaces long; moving it moves both of its "cells" at once and therefore both target cells must be "empty or itself"